# How to hide shortcuts in Qt menu

Tags: qt, user-interface, menuitem

I am using Qt (Embedded Linux) and I want to hide the shortcuts displayed right next to the menu items. I still want to use the shortcuts though.

ie;

```
Quit    Ctrl+Q
```

I want to get rid of the "Ctrl+Q" part of it.

```
Quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know that is not directly possible.

What you could do, though, is to not set any shortcuts for your menu items, and instead create the shortcuts separately using [QShortcut](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qshortcut.html#details). Then they won't appear next to any menu items, since they won't be associated with any.